# If condition in MongoDB for Nested JSON to retrieve a particular value

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongoid

I've nested JSON like this. I want to retrieve the value of "_value" in second level. i,e. "Living Organisms" This is my JSON document.

`{
  "name": "Biology Book",
  "data": {
    "toc": {
      "_version": "1",
      "ge": [
        {
          "_name": "The Fundamental Unit of Life",
          "_id": "5a",
          "ge": [
            {
              "_value": "Living Organisms",
              "_id": "5b"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}`

This is what I've tried, using the "_id", I want to retrieve it's "_value"

```
db.products.aggregate([{"$match":{ "data.toc.ge.ge._id": "5b"}}])
```

Comment: The query you have mentioned in your question works just fine. What is the issue you are facing?

Comment: @hushie Output should be ["Living Organisms"]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the closest I could get to the output you mentioned in the comment above. Hope it helps.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "data.toc.ge.ge._id": "5b"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$data.toc.ge"
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$data.toc.ge.ge"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      book: {
        $push: "$data.toc.ge.ge._value"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      first: {
        $arrayElemAt: [
          "$book",
          0
        ]
      },

    }
  }
])
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "first": "Living Organisms"
  }
]
```

You can check what I tried [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fb9IMkC1fCs)

Comment: @hussie Why are you using aggregate? can't we use 'find'?

Comment: @G.Brown to get to the result you asked for, I had to use aggregation, which allowed me to use `$project`, $unwind`. Which otherwise can't be used with find.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Mongoid:

```
(1..6).inject(Model.where('data.toc.ge.ge._id' => '5b').pluck('data.toc.ge.ge._value').first) { |v| v.values.first rescue v.first rescue v }
# => "Living Organisms"
```

6 is the number of containers to trim from the output (4 hashes and 2 arrays).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you only care about `_value`, so it sounds like you might want to use a projection:

```
db.products.aggregate([{"$match":{ "data.toc.ge.ge._id": "5b"}}, { "$project": {"data.toc.ge.ge._value": 1}}])
```